# Ant - replace string

Tags: android, ant, android-manifest, manifest

I am looking for possible solution,how to replace specific String in my Android.manifest

Currently I am using task:

```
    <replaceregexp flags="g" byline="false">
        <regexp pattern="&quot;com.package.Something&quot;"/> 
        <substitution expression="&quot;com.package.Extra.Something&quot;"/>
        <fileset dir="" includes="AndroidManifest.xml"/> 
    </replaceregexp>
```

All I need is to change every occurence of com.package to com.package.Extra, nevertheless what is before or after this statement. Up to now, this task replace occurence of **com.package.Something** by **com.package.Extra.Something**, but if I have in my manifest statement **com.package** (= without Sometning), is is not transfered. How to do that in code, that I want dynamically change only specified string and nothing more? It should by something like "If there is **com.package**, use **com.package.Something** instead and leave everything around exactly as it was before"

Hope you understand

Thanks

Comment: Please give us an example of what you have and what you want to have. Your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - use task < replace > as:

```
<replace file="AndroidManifest.xml" token="com.package" value="com.package.Extra"/>
```

`com.package` is replaced by `com.package.Extra`